# What throughput should I theoretically expect when reading sequentially from parallel NOR flash?

Tags: flash, bootloader, nor-flash

**Background:** I'm trying to minimize the boot time of a u-Boot+Linux system running on a fairly powerful T4240rdb powerpc development board. Once in U-boot the process is as follows: A linux kernel image, a ramdisk image, and a device tree blob is copied from a parallel NOR flash storage into RAM. `bootm` is then invoked on the images in RAM.

My issue is that the act of copying the images from flash is slow, on the order of 2-3 MiB/s.

The parallel NOR flash is a 128 MiB S29GL01GS with a 16-bit data bus with a random access time of ~100 ns, and page access of ~20 ns, with 16 word pages. Even in the worst case with only random accesses, my expectation is that I should be seeing ~20 MiB/s (16/100 = 0.16 bits/ns => 160 Mbits/s). Obviously this isn't the case. **Q:** Is my reasoning flawed? What speeds should I be seeing?

I'm fairly new to embedded, any help is appreciated.